Apache Beam: 'int' object has no attribute 'encode' [while running %]
I faced an error while trying to add the schema into PCollection:
My code:
with beam.Pipeline(options=beam_options) as p:
        notifications = (
                p
                | "read gcs noti" >> beam.io.ReadFromText('properties.jsonl')
                | "to json" >> beam.Map(json.loads)
                | "schema writer1" >> beam.Map(lambda x:beamSQL_schema.properties(**x))
                | "schema writer2" >> beam.Map(lambda x:x).with_output_types(beamSQL_schema.properties)
                | beam.Map(print)
            )
if __name__ == '__main__':
    # Run the pipeline.
    coders.registry.register_coder(beamSQL_schema.properties, coders.RowCoder)
    logging.getLogger(__name__).setLevel(logging.INFO)
    dwh_run()

everything would be fine without  "schema writer2" >> beam.Map(lambda x:x).with_output_types(beamSQL_schema.properties):
with beam.Pipeline(options=beam_options) as p:
        notifications = (
                p
                | "read gcs noti" >> beam.io.ReadFromText('properties.jsonl')
                | "to json" >> beam.Map(json.loads)
                | "schema writer1" >> beam.Map(lambda x:beamSQL_schema.properties(**x))
                | beam.Map(print)
            )
if __name__ == '__main__':
    # Run the pipeline.
    coders.registry.register_coder(beamSQL_schema.properties, coders.RowCoder)
    logging.getLogger(__name__).setLevel(logging.INFO)
    dwh_run()

Output:
properties(
uuid='bf1', 
read_timestamp='2024-03-31T16:23:07.938Z', 
source_timestamp='2024-03-31T16:23:07.938Z', 
object='public_dwh_entity_role_properties', 
read_method='postgresql-backfill', 
stream_name='projects/locations/streams', 
schema_key='ff24413219', sort_keys=[1138, ''], 
payload={'id': 35, 
  'public_identifier': '30ee', 
  'creation_timestamp': '2023-10-17T08:15:48.620Z', 
  'last_update_timestamp': '2023-10-17T08:15:48.620Z', 
  'entity_role_public_identifier': '3c53a', 
  'property_type': 'PERCENTAGE', 
  'property_value': '100.00'
}, 
source_metadata={'schema': 'public', 
  'table': 'properties', 
  'is_deleted': False, 
  'change_type': 'INSERT', 
  'tx_id': None, 
  'lsn': '', 
  'primary_keys': []
}
)

But when the with_output_types invoked:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "apache_beam/runners/common.py", line 1418, in apache_beam.runners.common.DoFnRunner.process
  File "apache_beam/runners/common.py", line 624, in apache_beam.runners.common.SimpleInvoker.invoke_process
  File "apache_beam/runners/common.py", line 1582, in apache_beam.runners.common._OutputHandler.handle_process_outputs
  File "apache_beam/runners/common.py", line 1695, in apache_beam.runners.common._OutputHandler._write_value_to_tag
  File "apache_beam/runners/worker/operations.py", line 239, in apache_beam.runners.worker.operations.SingletonElementConsumerSet.receive
  File "apache_beam/runners/worker/operations.py", line 198, in apache_beam.runners.worker.operations.ConsumerSet.update_counters_start
  File "apache_beam/runners/worker/opcounters.py", line 213, in apache_beam.runners.worker.opcounters.OperationCounters.update_from
  File "apache_beam/runners/worker/opcounters.py", line 265, in apache_beam.runners.worker.opcounters.OperationCounters.do_sample
  File "apache_beam/coders/coder_impl.py", line 1495, in apache_beam.coders.coder_impl.WindowedValueCoderImpl.get_estimated_size_and_observables
  File "apache_beam/coders/coder_impl.py", line 1506, in apache_beam.coders.coder_impl.WindowedValueCoderImpl.get_estimated_size_and_observables
  File "apache_beam/coders/coder_impl.py", line 209, in apache_beam.coders.coder_impl.CoderImpl.get_estimated_size_and_observables
  File "apache_beam/coders/coder_impl.py", line 1584, in apache_beam.coders.coder_impl.LengthPrefixCoderImpl.estimate_size
  File "apache_beam/coders/coder_impl.py", line 248, in apache_beam.coders.coder_impl.StreamCoderImpl.estimate_size
  File "apache_beam/coders/coder_impl.py", line 1769, in apache_beam.coders.coder_impl.RowCoderImpl.encode_to_stream
  File "apache_beam/coders/coder_impl.py", line 1170, in apache_beam.coders.coder_impl.SequenceCoderImpl.encode_to_stream
  File "apache_beam/coders/coder_impl.py", line 270, in apache_beam.coders.coder_impl.CallbackCoderImpl.encode_to_stream
  File "/home/user/Code/dwh-datflow-pubsub-noti/.env/lib/python3.7/site-packages/apache_beam/coders/coders.py", line 429, in encode
    return value.encode('utf-8')
AttributeError: 'int' object has no attribute 'encode'


Have you guys solved this issue? I was searching many pages but still don't know how to make it work :(
The schema I used:
class properties (NamedTuple):
    uuid: Optional[str]
    read_timestamp: Optional[str]
    source_timestamp: Optional[str]
    object: Optional[str]
    read_method: Optional[str]
    stream_name: Optional[str]
    schema_key: Optional[str]
    sort_keys: Optional[Sequence[str]]
    payload: Optional[
        NamedTuple(
            'payload',
            id = Optional[str],
            public_identifier= Optional[str],
            creation_timestamp=Optional[str],
            last_update_timestamp= Optional[str],
            entity_role_public_identifier=  Optional[str],
            property_type=  Optional[str],
            property_value=  Optional[str],
    ) # type: ignore
    ]
    source_metadata: Optional[ 
        NamedTuple(
        'source_metadata',
        schema= Optional[str],
        table= Optional[str],
        is_deleted= Optional[bool],
        change_type= Optional[str],
        tx_id= Optional[str],
        lsn= Optional[str],
        primary_keys= Optional[Sequence[str]],
    ) # type: ignore
    ]


Your sort_keys=[1138, ''] is a list containing an int. However, in your schema you specify this as a sequence of strings sort_keys: Optional[Sequence[str]]. When beam encounters the integer, it fails when trying to invoke the output types.

thanks, as you said I solved the schema type

one more question, is my defined schema correct?
I have converted all data elements to strings but met a new error at
| "schema writer2" >> beam.Map(lambda x:x).with_output_types(beamSQL_schema.properties)
The error:
'dict' object has no attribute 'id' [while running 'schema writer2']

Looks like an issue with your input data. In particular, as if your payload (sometimes) has not the key id present.
